# Error while processing references for EJB-in-WAR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, websphere, ejb

I develop Java enterprise application using maven on eclipse IDE
Application consist from ear,1 war,1 ejb and 1 jar file
when I build the ear outside eclipse with mvn install and deploy it on WebSphere its worked fine and this is ear structure:

```
Ear
  ejb.jar
  web.war
  /lib/datamodel.jar 
  META-INF/application.xml
```

the problem when I run the application and publish it from eclipse give me this exception

```
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: Error while processing references for EJB-in-WAR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fawry.maven.model.EmployeeDto
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:3434)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:750)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:564)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:635)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1034)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1413)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2273)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5482)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5698)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:673)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)

 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fawry.maven.model.EmployeeDto
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodsImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:977)
at java.lang.Class.getMethodSet(Class.java:1444)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1368)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.DeploymentUtil.getMethods(DeploymentUtil.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.EJBMDOrchestrator.finishBMDInitForReferenceContext(EJBMDOrchestrator.java:8091)
at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.finishBMDInitForReferenceContext(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:1678)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:3427)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fawry.maven.model.EmployeeDto
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:610)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:243)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:925)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:870)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:134)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:853)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:586)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:853)
... 80 more
```

Hint: EmployeeDto class exist in jar module

The dependency between modules like this:

```
web depend on ejb(web have ejb dependency in web pom)  and ejb depend on jar(ejb have jar dependency in ejb pom)
```

this is pom for ear module:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>ear</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ear</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>web</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>MavenDemo${build.number}</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <displayName>demo${build.number}</displayName>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
                    <generateModuleId>true</generateModuleId>
                    <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib/</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                            <artifactId>web</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/web</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
                            <bundleFileName>ejb.jar</bundleFileName>
                        </ejbModule>
                    </modules>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I am using:

```
eclipse 2022 
maven 3.8.4
java 8
websphere 8.5.5
```

any more information I can provide it , thanks for your help

Comment: What's in the stack of the ClassNotFoundException (most likely the deepest "caused by" in the NoClassDefFoundError stack)? That'll tell you what class loaders are being used - app/WAR loaders are of type CompoundClassLoader in WAS 8.5. My best guess is that something is preventing the jar from being added to the EAR class path, but it'd be hard to tell that without trace logs.

Comment: Since you said Maven was able to package the EAR correctly but you hit a problem doing a "publish", this suggests an issue in the Eclipse tooling, with some part of the WTP Java EE function.     I don't know the answer, but I'll include some links/references from RAD doc in case it helps somehow.   Note that since this WTP function is broader than just WebSphere you might find useful clues in non-RAD/WebSphere doc too.   I also know sometimes right-click "Maven->Update Project" helps in general using Maven & WTP in Eclipse.  Possibly worth a try.

Comment: Some WebSphere/RAD links:  1. overview - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/radfws/9.7?topic=developing-maven-  2. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/radfws/9.7?topic=dependencies-adding-other-modules   3. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/radfws/9.7?topic=projects-working-dependencies    4. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/radfws/9.7?topic=preferences-setting

Comment: @Jarid
 Thanks for your reply first
I updated the post with all exception trace

Comment: Can you try comparing the two packages?   Comparing 1) the target EAR produced by the Maven build (in the target/xxx.ear location)  with 2) the EAR exported via:  File->Export-> Java EE -> EAR file.     I think that 2) would be representative of the contents of the "Publish" operation..maybe it will suggest a clue.